# Angular using ng-repeat variable in nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeat which iterates over an array of values:

```
var englishList = ["abo", "ser", "vol", "con", "giv", "blo"];
$scope.englishList = englishList;
```

Is there a way to loop over these values in an ng-repeat and use the returned value as part of a nested ng-repeat?

```
  <div ng-repeat="api in englishList">
    <div ng-repeat="result in searchData.abo | filter:searchText">
      <li>{{result.title}} {{result.shortname}}</li>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Ideally, I'd like this line to interpolate the each ng-repeat value from $scope.englishList:

```
<div ng-repeat="result in searchData.{{api}} | filter:searchText">
```

Is there a way to do this in angular?

Comment: maybe you're looking for this: searchData[api] rather than searchData.{{api}}, 
To get a value of an object in JS, either you do 
object.key
or 
object[key]
if key is a variable, you should go with the 2nd one object[key]

Comment: what u want to achive using this ?

Comment: searchData has the keys of englishList. I'm planning on looping through all of the page data on a site which is contained in searchData and filtering based on input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this, surely:

```
<div ng-repeat='api in englishList'>
  <div ng-repeat='item in searchData[api]'>
    <!-- uses the value of 'api' as a key in 'searchData' -->
    <!-- you do not need to use interpolation here as these are already expressions -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't really give a complete example as your code is not exactly obvious in how you would want to use the nested type, but the above snippet should give you an idea of HOW to use nested repeats.

I would advise you use an object model like so

```
{ "api": {
  "foo": [ "bar", "baz", "qux" ]
}}
```

Rather than having two different arrays. This should make it less brittle. Remember that your view's logic should ideally be as simple as possible and it shouldn't have to do much manipulation on the data given to it to work. I would say that iterating one array and then iterating another using the values of array 1 as keys of array 2 is maybe a bit too much for the view to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the bracket notation to dynamically access a property :

```
<div ng-repeat="api in englishList">
    <div ng-repeat="result in searchData[api] | filter: searchText" >
        <li>{{result.title}}, {{result.shortname}}</li>
    </div>
</div>
```

***Snippet :***

```js
angular.module('demoApp', []).controller('DemoController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.englishList = ["abo", "ser", "vol", "con"];;

    $scope.searchData = {
        abo: [{
            title: 'title abo',
            shortname: 'shortname abo'
        }],
        ser: [{
            title: 'title ser 1',
            shortname: 'shortname ser 1'
        }, {
            title: 'title ser 2',
            shortname: 'shortname ser 2'
        }],
        vol: [{
            title: 'title vol',
            shortname: 'shortname vol'
        }],
        con: [{
            title: 'title con',
            shortname: 'shortname con'
        }]
    };
});
```

```css
p {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="DemoController">
    <div>Search <input type="text" ng-model="searchText"/></div>
    <div ng-repeat="api in englishList">
        <p>{{api}}</p>
        <div ng-repeat="result in searchData[api] | filter: searchText" >
            <li>{{result.title}}, {{result.shortname}}</li>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```